# Finding maximum and minimum values in each column of 2d array Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the max value in each column of a 2d array in Java. The english version of the question asking to find the max mark for each subject/module. I have implemented a for-loop to find the max value just not sure how to isolate to each column.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double max=0;
    double mark;
    double id;
    double [][] studs = new double [2][3];

    Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int studentNo = 0; studentNo < 2; studentNo++) {
        System.out.println("enter student ID number for student " + (studentNo+1));
        id = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
        studs[studentNo][0] = id;
        for (int moduleNo = 1; moduleNo < 3; moduleNo++) {
            System.out.println("Enter users mark for module " + moduleNo);
            mark = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
            studs[studentNo][moduleNo] = mark;
        }
    }

    for (int col=1;col<3;col++){
        for (int row=0;row<2;row++){
            if(studs [row][col]>max) {
                max=studs[row][col];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(max);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `max` at the start of each new column.

Comment: thanks, this the sort of stuff you miss when learning from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is thinking in a different way: why not putting Subjects in rows and putting Students in columns? Then you just scan each row.